# Android - getting supported Color Effects

Tags: android, android-camera

SO

There is an API for that: [Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedColorEffects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedColorEffects%28%29)
But it doesn't properly work on my Samsung Galaxy S Plus. It returns 9 color effects, but actually supported only three of them.

I came to that conclusion after launching the 'native' camera app - there are only threee effects available there (sepia, negative and black'n'white). And these work in my application. When I try to apply others form that list that is returned by getSupportedColorEffects() - nothing happens.

Does anybody know how it is possible to find supported color effects?

Here is how I am getting those effects:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

    List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    List<String> effects = parameters.getSupportedColorEffects();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find a plausible solution? I have the same problem for Samsung Galaxy S4 front camera. `getSupportedColorEffects()` returns 15 effects but only a fraction of them are actually supported.

Comment: I also have the same issue on Galaxy S4 back and front cameras, and can't find a solution about a week :/ Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have found a bug in Android, or at least the build of it on that device.  It sounds like someone else had a similar issue on a different device: [android camera samsung galaxy i9003 setParameters faild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779261/android-camera-samsung-galaxy-i9003-setparameters-faild).

One thought as a possible workaround: Are you able to successfully set the color effects that aren't working?  That is, do you check that `getColorEffect()` is not `null` after calling `setColorEffect()`?  If you get `null` for the ones that don't work, you can just follow up your `getSupportedColorEffects()` with a loop to verify each.

If that doesn't work, but rather the device is claiming to support effects that it silently ignores, then I'm not sure there's anything you can do about it.